# Execute command before shutdown/reboot

Tags: shutdown, reboot, execute-command

I have a machine running a couple of vagrant VM. The problem I have is that sometimes I forget to shutdown those VM before I shutdown or reboot my machine. Because of that my machine get stuck with this message: `waiting for vboxnet0 to become free`

I searched about solutions and I found this page :

http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3348-ubuntu-executing-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown

I tried what they for shutdown, but it doesn't work.

I wrote an sh file for that command:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/workspace/git/mediaservice
vagrant halt
```

any suggestions?

Comment: The method in the link is valid and works on all linux version so your script is wrong ;) The user is not known at shutdown since it is done by user root. So drop the "~" and make it a full path.

Comment: Does it work? I followed a similar manuel like https://gist.github.com/ymc-geha/8416723 but didnt work for me on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @user2135804 I thought it did.. but actually it didn't work for Vagrant.. I tried with other stuff and it worked well.

Comment: I'm having this problem, as well. How did you fix it?

Comment: @turboHz it is still not fixed.

Comment: By the way, the bug you're describing is [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12264).

Comment: As seen in the bug report, this has been fixed and will be included with VirtualBox 4.3.29.

Comment: @pomsky whilst the answer seem to cover all case scenarios, the question is about executing a command just before shutdown, logout or reboot (not after reboot). But thanks for the link, that is useful too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your vagrant VMs are using VirtualBox, you can modify `/etc/default/virtualbox` and change the line that reads:

```
SHUTDOWN_USERS=""
```

to

```
SHUTDOWN_USERS="all"
```

That fixed it for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Actually there is an open ticket in virtual box connected with this. https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12264. I would sugges using `SHUTDOWN_USERS=\`cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd\`` instead of `SHUTDOWN_USERS="all"`

Comment: I'm also on Ubuntu 14.04 with Vagrant using VirtualBox, but I don't have any `/etc/default/virtualbox` file...

Answer (score 29):

To execute a script at shutdown or reboot:

1. save your script in /etc/rc6.d
2. Make it executable: `sudo chmod +x K99_script`

Notes:

- The script in rc6.d must be with no .sh extension
- The name of your script must begin with K99 to run at the right time.
- The scripts in this directory are executed in alphabetical order.

[source](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3348-ubuntu-executing-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown)

Comment: Indeed. Naming it properly so that it runs at the right time is very important.

Comment: I put a script in /etc/rc6.d and it did not run on shutdown. I put it in /etc/rc0.d and it did run on shutdown.  Probably, rc.6 is only for reboot.

Comment: @Erel Segal-Halevi I just tried adding a K99 script  to /etc/rc6.d and it didn't execute. Looking at the other scripts, there is a line **bold K10reboot -> ../init.d/reboot **code ,  so it looks like a K99 script will NEVER be executed!!

Comment: The answer from Ravi below is a better choice because it uses symlinks to ensure script runs on both shutdown  AND reboot. I also think most system files tend to take tis approach.

Comment: rc.6 seem to be only for reboot as others mentioned. [See](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83753/123769)

Comment: Doesn't work for me, xubuntu20.04, 2020-10-20

Comment: You may need to add INIT INFO as a comment, see more at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356838/ubuntu-20-04-running-script-at-shutdown-restart

Answer (score 17):

1. Create a shell executable file with your script in /etc/init.d/ directory.
2. Since this has to be executed during shutdown or reboot need to create softlinks in /etc/rc0.d/ and /etc/rc6.d

Example:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/<your_file> /etc/rc0.d/k99stop_vm
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/<your_file> /etc/rc6.d/k99stop_vm
sudo chmod a+x /etc/init.d/<your_file>
```

Comment: `chmod` changes the permission flags of the link target, which is the same for both arguments. Specifying them both is redundant.

Comment: You may need to add INIT INFO as a comment, see more at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356838/ubuntu-20-04-running-script-at-shutdown-restart

Answer (score 6):

For Ubuntu 14.10 you something like `RC04` not `RC99`

**What to do from scratch**

1. Create a script at `/etc/init.d/scriptName`

   - Make sure `#!/bin/bash` is at the top of the script so that Linux knows it's a Bash script
   - Make sure you run `chmod +x /etc/init.d/scriptName` to make the script executable
2. Make a symlink: `ln -s /etc/init.d/scriptName /etc/rc6.d/K04scriptName`

**Steps I went through**

1. I tried unsuccessfully to use  [Ubuntu - Executing a script at startup and shutdown](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3348-ubuntu-executing-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown)
2. I found [Ubuntu 14.10 shutdown script with rc0.d (rc6.d, rc.d)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150313185740/http://ubuntu.flowconsult.at/linux/ubuntu-14-10-shutdown-script-with-rc0-d-rc6-rcd/)
3. I changed from `/etc/rc6.d/RC99linkName` to `/etc/rc6.d/RC04linkName` and it works

Comment: It might not be the cleanest or the neatest, but it sure does work for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, xubuntu20.04, 2020-10-20

Comment: You may need to add INIT INFO as a comment, see more at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356838/ubuntu-20-04-running-script-at-shutdown-restart

Answer (score 2):

You can find a solution here: [Suspend/resume all Vagrant boxes on system shutdown/startup](http://www.ollegustafsson.com/en/vagrant-suspend-resume/).

There is a simple init script that suspends all running boxes before shutting down.

**Installation**

Edit `/etc/init.d/vagrant-boxes` and paste the script from above article and save.
Or [download it from here](http://www.ollegustafsson.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/vagrant-boxes.txt) and save it to `/etc/init.d/vagrant-boxes`.
On debian/ubuntu etc, run

```
# update-rc.d vagrant-boxes defaults 99 01
```

> Number 99 is the sequence number and should be larger than (in my case Virtualbox number 20,which by the way is the default on Debian distros). The second number is the sequence when shutting down the computer. So, it might be good to do first of all.