# Run commands on system shutdown/reboot/logout

Tags: 14.04, bash, shutdown, restart, logout

I would like to run certain aliases and simple commands when system shuts down or reboots or when I simply log out of system. This would help a lot as I usually forget about shutting down vagrant ( vagrant halt ) and some other terminal commands.
Do we have some kind of bash files or scripts so I can achieve this on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Take a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up

Comment: Check the answers of http://askubuntu.com/questions/416299/execute-command-before-shutdown-reboot (duplicate?)

Answer (score -1):

Runlevel 0 corresponds to shutdown, and Runlevel 6 corresponds to reboot.

The /etc/rc[0-6].d/ directories contain scripts that are executed when a particular runlevel is initiated.

So you can write a script that contains commands to shutdown various processes, and store that script in /etc/rc0.d/K99_yourscript and make it executable. This will run your script at shutdown. Copy the script over to /etc/rc6.d/K99_yourscript to have it execute on reboot as well.

Comment: This is not the recommended way to manage System V init scripts. For an overview on the topic read `/etc/init.d/README` and [`update-rc.d(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/update-rc.d.8.html).